# Firebase: Add a Additional Collection to a Document Unhandled Promise Rejection

Tags: javascript, firebase, async-await

I currently have a Collection | Document | Collection Firestore.
I want to search for a specific collection within the document and if the user ID matches, then update. If the user ID is not in the collection, then I want to add a new collection.

The collection update aspect works, but getting a Promise Rejection when adding to the collection via .set().

```
if (!query.empty) {
      console.log('event leaderboard exists in db');
      for (let i in leaderboard) {
        const result = leaderboard[i].data();

        for (let y in result) {
          const userLeaderboard = result[y];
          
          if (userLeaderboard.uid === currentUser.uid) {
            // User exists in record and update score
            return query.docs[i].ref.update({
              score: increaseBy,
            });
          } else {
            // User does not exist and need to add to record
            addUserToLeaderboard();
            
          }
        }
      }
```

...

```
const addUserToLeaderboard = async() => {
let userLeaderboard = {
  uid: currentUser.uid,
  score: currentTrivia.points,
  banned: false,
};

const leaderboardRef = db.collection('leaderboard').where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', eventId);
await leaderboardRef.set(userLeaderboard, { merge: true });
```

}

Comment: Inside the `addUserToLeaderboard` function by `let userLeaderBoard = {...` line you define a new  `userLeaderboard` but never return it. Any assignment to it woudn't effect the one defined in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `set` on a query.

If you want to update the one document with the given ID, use:

```
const leaderboardRef = db.collection('leaderboard').doc(eventId);
await leaderboardRef.set(userLeaderboard, { merge: true });
```

If you want to update (potentially multiple) items matching a query, you'll need to execute the query, loop over the results, and update each document in turn. But that' doesn't seem to be needed here.